# Click e dblclick em javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Sou novo em JS e estou aprendendo, e estou fazendo um jogo da velha no qual o primeiro clique é para o jogador1 colocar o "x", e dois cliques para o jogador2 colocar o "o", qual séria a melhor maneira de fazer?  pois não posso adicionar um "onclick" ou um "ondblclick" na tag, estava tentando fazer por addEventListener pegando a classe, porém não consegui faze-lo funcional.

estou usando uma table para criar o tabuleiro: código atualizado do js atual.

```js
function testejogada(){
alert("funcionou");

}

function testejogada1(){
alert("funcionou1");
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
var classe = document.querySelector(".espaco");
classe.addEventListener('dblclick', function(){ testejogada()

});

classe.addEventListener('click', function(){ testejogada1()

});
});
```

```html
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td><img class="espaco" src="img/default.png" id="casa1-1" /></td>
    <td><img class="espaco" src="img/default.png" id="casa1-2" /></td>
    <td><img class="espaco" src="img/default.png" id="casa1-3" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><img class="espaco" src="img/default.png" id="casa2-1" /></td>
    <td><img class="espaco" src="img/default.png" id="casa2-2" /></td>
    <td><img class="espaco" src="img/default.png" id="casa2-3" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><img class="espaco" src="img/default.png" id="casa3-1" /></td>
    <td><img class="espaco" src="img/default.png" id="casa3-2" /></td>
    <td><img class="espaco" src="img/default.png" id="casa3-3" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" id="ganhador"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Poste também o código .js por favor...

Comment: no caso estava tentando usar algo tipo isso:
/////////////
function testejogada(){
 alert("funcionou");

}



var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.espaco');

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {

  elements[i].addEventListener('click', testejogada);


  }

Comment: Poste o código que escreve o X e o O nas casas.

Comment: no caso meu problema não é como conseguir botar o X ou o O e sim pegar o  1 clique ou 2 cliques e conseguir fazer duas operações distintas, eu ainda não sei como fazer isto e tudo que tentei é no mínimo falho.

Comment: Poste o seu js de forma que possamos analisa-lo e entender sua lógica. Aí te ajudaremos a corrigir. Vamos atuar nas falhas apenas

Comment: então, no comentário acima eu postei de uma forma que tentei fazer; --> código ////// function testejogada(){ alert("funcionou"); } var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.espaco'); for (i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) { elements[i].addEventListener('click', testejogada); } /////

Comment: editei o post com o código em js

Comment: Utilizar o click duplo é uma prerrogativa? pq tem meios mais simples de fazer isso

Comment: sim, tem que usar o click duplo, no caso é para aprendizado, eu consegui "arrumar" o meu código, mas preciso colocar um "time" pra diferenciar os dois clicks, vou editar ali no post, porém tbm não sei como fazer esse "time".

Comment: @pdm, você não deveria usar o dbclick e o click no mesmo elemento, nestes casos. Mesmo que você consiga setar o listener, vai cair sempre no click. Não vai dar tempo você disparar o segundo evento após o primeiro, entende? Segue ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897558/listen-to-double-click-not-click

Comment: verdade é bem ruim de usar, teria alguma outra maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: @pdm, uma alternativa é fazer da seguinte forma: https://codepen.io/valdeir2000/pen/pLqMmM

Comment: @ValdeirPsr obrigado vendo seu código consegui ter uma outra visão de como usar o js, mas desta já forma consegui fazer no caso com 1 clique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma, alternando os atributos `onclick` e `ondblclick` à medida que os jogadores vão jogando.

Criei uma classe `jogado` para desabilitar cliques nas casas que já foram marcadas (coloquei um fundo vermelho de exemplo).

**Exemplo:**

```js
var jogador1 = true;
var jogador2 = false;
var jogador_vez = 1;

function alteraJogador(){

   var casas = document.body.querySelectorAll(".espaco");
   
   for(var x=0; x<casas.length; x++){

      casas[x].setAttribute("onclick", jogador1 ? "joga(this)" : "");
      casas[x].setAttribute("ondblclick", jogador1 ? "": "joga(this)");
      
      // aqui eu removo os atributos onde tem classe "jogado"
      // para não aceitar mais cliques
      if(casas[x].classList.contains("jogado")){
         casas[x].removeAttribute("onclick");
         casas[x].removeAttribute("ondblclick");
      }
   }
   
}

function joga(casa){
   jogador1 = !jogador1;
   jogador2 = !jogador2;

   casa.classList.add("jogado");
   
   alteraJogador();

   if(jogador_vez == 1){
      // faz algo quando o jogador 1 jogar
      console.log("Jogador 1 jogou.");
   }else{
      // faz algo quando o jogador 2 jogar
      console.log("Jogador 2 jogou.");
   }

   jogador_vez = jogador1 ? 1 : 2;
   
   console.log("Vez do jogador "+jogador_vez+" jogar");
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", alteraJogador );
```

```css
.jogado{
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<table align="center">
<tr>
   <td><img class="espaco" src="img/default.png"  id="casa1-1"/></td>
   <td><img class="espaco" src="img/default.png"  id="casa1-2"/></td>
   <td><img class="espaco" src="img/default.png"  id="casa1-3"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td><img class="espaco" src="img/default.png"  id="casa2-1"/></td>
   <td><img class="espaco" src="img/default.png"  id="casa2-2"/></td>
   <td><img class="espaco" src="img/default.png"  id="casa2-3"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td><img class="espaco" src="img/default.png"  id="casa3-1"/></td>
   <td><img class="espaco" src="img/default.png"  id="casa3-2"/></td>
   <td><img class="espaco" src="img/default.png"  id="casa3-3"/></td>
</tr>

<tr >
   <td colspan="3" id="ganhador"></td>
</tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: perfeito! muito obrigado pela ajuda! é justamente isso que estava precisando, não estava ciente sobre o setAttribute e do remove, isso ajudou muito no meu aprendizado =)

Answer (score 0):

Bom suponho  que o  que você precisa fazer é um pouco mais complexo do que isso, então eu  usei a biblioteca jquery  que [pode  ser baixada aqui](https://jquery.com/)

O que acontece você não vai conseguir colocar um dbclick  e um onclick no mesmo  elemento sempre que de  um dbclick o  onclick vai ser chamado então para isso  eu  criei  uma função  com um timer  para que seja reconhecida o  numero de clickes

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function testejogada(){
        alert("funcionou");

    }

    function testejogada1(){
        alert("funcionou1");
    }
var classe = $(".espaco");
console.log(classe)

$.each(classe, function(k,v){
var DELAY = 700, clicks = 0, timer = null;



    $(this).on("click", function(e){

        clicks++;  //conta os clicks

        if(clicks === 1) {

            timer = setTimeout(function() {

                testejogada();  //execeuta o click unico action    
                clicks = 0;             //apos executado zera o timer

            }, DELAY);

        } else {

            clearTimeout(timer);    //previne o click unico action
            testejogada1();         //executa  o  dbclick 
            clicks = 0;             //apos fazer a ação reseta o timer
        }

    })
    .on("dblclick", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();  //cancela   o double click default do navegador
    });

});
})
```

Você pode ver o  [exemplo  funcionando  aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/83025/)

Comment: muito obrigado, realmente era isso =D

Answer (score 0):

A minha sugestão é que use apenas o evento `click`, e faça a alteração entre `cruz` e `circulo`.

```js
var game = [ 
  [null, null, null], 
  [null, null, null], 
  [null, null, null], 
]

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var onSquareCircle = function (event) {
  var hasCircle = this.classList.contains("circle");
  this.classList.toggle("circle", !hasCircle)
  this.classList.toggle("cross", hasCircle)
  
  var x = parseInt(this.dataset.x)
  var y = parseInt(this.dataset.y)
  game[x][y] = hasCircle ? 1 : 0
};

[].forEach.call(squares, function (square) {
  square.addEventListener("click", onSquareCircle);
})
```

```css
.square {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-size: calc(100% - 5px);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.cross {
  background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/128/128397.svg')
}

.circle {
  background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/64/64299.svg')
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-x="0" data-y="0" class="square"></td>
      <td data-x="0" data-y="1" class="square"></td>
      <td data-x="0" data-y="2" class="square"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-x="1" data-y="0" class="square"></td>
      <td data-x="1" data-y="1" class="square"></td>
      <td data-x="1" data-y="2" class="square"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-x="2" data-y="0" class="square"></td>
      <td data-x="2" data-y="1" class="square"></td>
      <td data-x="2" data-y="2" class="square"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```